# Anomaly log file type detection and predict future log error

Tags: python, networking, anomaly-detection, log-analysis

I am working on anomaly log analysis methods such as drain approach to use to structure log data into structure data. We have lots of log file and we have no idea this specific log file belong to which software? like android, HDF and etc.

1. How we recognize log file type?
2. How we can predict future log analysis error based on current log data?